# Where is the source code implementation of gethostbyname() function?

Tags: c, implementation, glibc, gethostbyname

From glibc tree, I can see only file `gethstbynm.c` (*glibc-2.32/inet/gethstbynm.c*), but there is no implementation code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


#define LOOKUP_TYPE struct hostent
#define FUNCTION_NAME   gethostbyname
#define DATABASE_NAME   hosts
#define ADD_PARAMS  const char *name
#define ADD_VARIABLES   name
#define BUFLEN      1024
#define NEED_H_ERRNO    1

#define HANDLE_DIGITS_DOTS  1

#include <nss/getXXbyYY.c>
```

I would like to find the implementation as [https://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Sockets-Networking/dp/0131411551](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) suggest:

```
static struct hostent host ;
/* result stored here */
struct hostent *
gethostbyname (const char *hostname)
{
return (gethostbyname2 (hostname, family));
}
```

What file stores the implementation?

EDIT:
uname -a:

Linux 5.8.0-40-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 15 11:05:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: see edits......

Answer (score 2):

On linux `gethostbyname()` is declared in `glibc/resolv/netdb.h` ([see here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/resolv/netdb.h.html#gethostbyname)),  pseudo defined via macros in `inet/gethstbynm.c` ([see here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/inet/gethstbynm.c.html#_M/FUNCTION_NAME)), and finally defined in `nss/getXXbyYY.c` ([see here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nss/getXXbyYY.c.html#93)).

Comment: Though it should be pointed out that some programs--notably big browers like Firefox and Chrome--do not use the OS version, but do it themselves.

Comment: @milanHrabos: the function is defined exactly at the line indicated in the third link in this answer. The definition is obscured by the use of macros but the definitions are visible in the second link. So this is the best answer you're going to find.